# Broadcast a message to everyone periodically using Django channels

Tags: django

I'm new to Django channels. I created a WebSocket and I want to send some info to every user periodically (broadcast periodically).

Each user connects to the WebSocket when goes to my website and see those info on top of each page.

I have no idea whether it is necessary to create a group or not, and if it is necessary, how to create it...

So how can I send info to every visitor periodically(in an efficient way)?

May be something like this:

```
class Consumer(AsyncConsumer):
    async def websocket_connect(self, event):
        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.accept",
        })
        while True:
            await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                {
                    "text": 'Hello user!'
                }
            )
            # OR
            await self.send({
                "type": "websocket.send",
                "text": 'Hello user!'
            })
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: If it is not the best way to implement this feature, So what is the best way to get (for example) an API data in backend lively and send it to everyone in frontend.